# How can I manage my timer on different application states, I'm using MVVM approach?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a timer that works fine, the problem I'm having is to keep the timer running when the app is on sleep mode or minimized or when I hit the back button, the timer should only stop when I hit the stop button of which I have done.

```
/// <summary>
/// Starts the timer
/// </summary>
private void StartCommandAction()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = _cancellationTokenSource; // safe copy
    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),() =>
    {
        if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                var totalTimeInt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtTotalTime.Value) ? 0  : int.Parse(TxtTotalTime.Value);
                var totalSec = (int)TotalSeconds.TotalSeconds;
                TimeSpan _TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(totalTimeInt, 0, totalSec); //TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TotalSeconds.TotalSeconds);
                LblTime = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", _TimeSpan.Hours, _TimeSpan.Minutes, _TimeSpan.Seconds);
                IsVisibleTimerLabel = true;
                Count();
            });

            return true;
        }
    });

    IsVisibleButtonStart = false;
    IsVisibleButton = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I would have put timers and message-pump-aware types in a _view model_

Comment: Device is a class that contains a number of properties and methods to help developers customize layout and functionality on a per-platform basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your source code, the following struck me: You are expecting the timer event to be raised exactly once each second and taking the textual representation to calculate a total time. This may work for the current timer implementation, but this is not guaranteed. Even worse, your implementation is not robust against different timer implementations.

When you sum up your times each iteration, the error of the total time will grow and grow. Depending on your use-case this may be irrelevant, but luckily, the remedy to this issue is the remedy to the issue you're trying to solve, too.

*My suggestion is:* Refrain from summing up the times, but introduce a fixed reference. In the first order this might be a `DateTime` (if precision was a matter to you, your solution would look different, hence the precision of `DateTime.Now` will do), but a `Stopwatch` would do the trick either.

When starting the timer the first time, store the current `DateTime.Now` value in a member variable and use this to calculate the elapsed time

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = _cancellationTokenSource; // safe copy
this._startedAt = DateTime.Now;

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),() =>
{
    if (cts.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            TimeSpan _TimeSpan = DateTime.Now - _startedAt;
            LblTime = _TimeSpan.ToString("hh:mm:ss);
            IsVisibleTimerLabel = true;
            Count();
        });

        return true;
    }
});
```

(**Please note:** To format a `TimeSpan` you can use the `ToString` method with a format string. Please see [the documentation of `TimeSpan.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) on how to format `TimeSpan` values according to your needs)

This way, when returning to the page, you can just restart the timer (**without setting `_startedAt`**, though). Because you've already set `_startedAt`, the timer will continue to run and show the correct time.